# HTML codes showing up when using ng-bind-html

Tags: html, angularjs

The Output in the inspect element:

```
<div ng-bind-html="job.description" class="ng-binding">
    "<p><strong>Our Responsibilities</strong></p>"
</div>
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.20/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.3.20/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

var myApp = angular.module('rivigoApp', ['ngSanitize']);

<div ng-bind-html="job.description"></div>
```

How do I do to make it compile the HTML in the output? I believe the main issue is with the quotes "" but I'm unable to figure out how to proceed. I've tried using various other methods.

Comment: Please share how `job.description` is defined in your controller.

Comment: in general, if you are storing HTML in javascript variables, you are probably not using angular in the best manner.

Comment: {{job.description}} is just another field.

Answer (score 1):

inject $sce Service in your controller and use it like below

```
app.controller('mainCtrl',function($sce , $scope){
     $scope.job = {
        description : $sce.trustAsHtml("<p><strong>Our Responsibilities</strong></p>")
    };

    })
```

`$sce` [Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Comment: Thanks. However, that's not the only html tag and so hard coding it doesn't make sense. The {{job.description}} is also 2 pages long of html codes.